# Clean way to re-route user that isn't logged in with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I guess I could always add login in `WillTransitionTo` which would do a call to the store via Redux to verify that the user is logged in but this seems a bit hacky, especially since since I have to add `WillTransitionTo()` logic to every single component.

Anyone have any better ideas?  I'm going to work toward wiring something into `isAuthorized` with the `onEnter`.

This is the root root of the application which performs the react-router wire-up.

**react-router : 2.0.4**

**react: 15.0.2**

```
const store = configureStore();


function isAuthorized() {

}

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
     <Router history={browserHistory}>

        <Route path="/" component={Application} onEnter={isAuthorized}>
            <IndexRoute component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path="dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="items" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="item-categories" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="modifiers" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="taxes" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="discounts" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="orders" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="users" component={DashboardPage} />
        </Route>
     </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("application")
);
```

Note that the example in auth-flow utilizes `localStorage` to persist userAccess tokens, etc.  I really don't want to use `localStorage` or cookies at this time.  I want to minimize the complexity and store the login state in the store(state.user).  I don't specifically want to go into the reason for this other than to say that there is a large amount of information that comes the authentication step that needs to be persisted to the store.

Comment: You've been very unclear with the context. We can understand you want Authentication failure to redirect to a login page, but you make no mention of your router and auth set up. The "clean way" will depend entirely on those two things, as the router will do the redirect, and the auth strategy will provide your hooks for determining who has access.

Comment: As you mentioned React, I'll assume you're using their router. Here's the react-router Auth-flow example, which should be a good starting point. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

Comment: let me edit the question with more context, thanks guys.  The auth-flow example wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

This solution worked for me which is a slight modification on the answer:

```
function isAuthorized(nextState, replace) {
    if (nextState.location.pathname === "/login") {
        return;
    }
    const state = store.getState();
    if (state.user && state.user.loggedIn === true) {
        return;
    }
    replace("/login");
}


render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Application} onEnter={(nextState, replace) => isAuthorized(nextState, replace)}>
                <IndexRoute component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
                <Route path="dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="items" component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="item-categories" component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="modifiers" component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="taxes" component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="discounts" component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="orders" component={DashboardPage} />
                <Route path="users" component={DashboardPage} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider >,
    document.getElementById("application")
);
```

Comment: Although it's valid, the thing is here you're directly accessing the `store` in `isAuthorized method` This will work if you placed the `isAuthorized method` within `app.js*` file, But if you're using separate files for `middlewares` then it wont work since it wont have access to the `store` variable.

Comment: @RandomUser: you may wish to point the OP to your comment, by pinging the question - I posted this on their behalf, so they won't be notified.

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing something like

```
<Route
  path="/"
  component={Application}
  onEnter={ (nextState, replace) => { isAuthorized(nextState, replace, store) } } >
```

And in your `isAuthorized` function

```
function isAuthorized( nextState, replace, store ) {
  // Now you have access to the store, you can
  const state = store.getState();

  // your logic to validate whether the user is logged in or not
  if ( state.user && state.user.loggedIn === true ) {
    // this user is authenticated
    // continue..
  }
  else {
    // unauthenticated user, redirect the user to login page
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: thanks man let me give this a whirl, this looks it should work.