# Handling login on react-router redux with redirections

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I was trying to implementing login feature in my react-router redux app.

Following is the scenario

**User logs in and he is redirected to his dashboard.**

For this when the person enters ID/pass and presses on submit and on success on API call I replace the browserHistory with /app/dashboard. So far so good.

**User can select sub sections inside dashboard**

So now he can choose sub pages under dashboard and goes to /app/dashboard/:page and it all works fine.

Now say if he reloads the page here it gets redirected to /app/dashboard. This is mainly because on my mount point which is my **App Component(/app)** is dispatch an action for initial authentication.

This action checks if user is already logged in(which I track from cookies). If he is, he is redirected to dashboard else he is taken to login page.

When I reload /app/dashboard/:page it takes me /app/dashboard because of this initAuth() action is dispatch on App Component.

To handle this what I did was I use the **location** from props under the components.

This takes of 2 scenarios.

**Scenario 1**

When I fire `initAuth()` I fire by passing `pathname` from `location` as parameter. If it is login I redirect to the homepage else I leave it.

**Scenario 2**
Similarly when I log in  I read `ownProps` from `mapDispatchToProps` and check if the pathname if login I redirect it to `/app/dashboard`.

This way only if he user is coming from login he is re-directed to dashboard and other pages are not redirected to dashboard.

So I created a function which handles both above scenarios

```
if(path === constants.LOGIN_URL_PATHANAME){
  browserHistory.replace(constants.DASHBOARD_URL_PATHNAME)
}
```

So though I implemented this but I think there can be a better solution to handle this. Can you please share your feedback?

Comment: I think this is bad and `middlewares` are best suited for this. I use `react-router` middleware, I call the middleware on the `route +/ groups` i want to protect and the middleware checks if the user is logged in based on `access token` stored in `localStirage`. If logged in continue.. otherwise redirect the user to the `login` page.

Comment: is you app open source? Would definitely love to take a look at the code.. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Checkout this question its similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538541/clean-way-to-re-route-user-that-isnt-logged-in-with-react/39539228#39539228 If nothing helps, I will open source part of my code.

Comment: yup thats what i have done,  using onEnter checking for authentication. Can you please share part of your code? :)